# can capacitor increase flow/quantity of water in water pump

Tags: capacitor

can capacitor increase flow/quantity of water in water pump. we are already using capacitor of 25 uf. can water quantity be increased if we use capacitor of 30 uf or any higher which u suggest.

Answer (score 3):

No, the wrong sized capacitor will make things worse.

The purpose of a run capacitor is to energise a second winding in the motor. It's capacitance is chosen to produce the correct phase difference between the windings. A smaller value will produce less torque. A higher value will overheat the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxcLm8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

See

- [Single-phase induction motors](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_2/chpt_13/9.html)
- [Motor Capacitor FAQ](http://www.temcoindustrialpower.com/product_selection.html?p=motor_capacitor_faq#run_cap)

Comment: Yes, please, would you mind extending the answer? I wish I knew exactly what the role of a capacitor here is...